# 12.04 cd install failure. No options , simply splash screen forever

Tags: installation, boot, live-cd

I have problems with 12.04 installation from live cd.

the installation option never show up. just splash screen and no responses from any key.

I tried it on my laptop and desktop. same result.

Answer (score 1):

Hit ESC at startup, select your language (default is english), then hit F6. From the selections in F6 - enabled acpi=off and nomodeset. Then try booting.

Comment: Its not responding to `Esc` unfortunately.